# Declaring a protocol with a type requirement in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

How can I declare a property like so:

```
import SpriteKit

protocol Pausible where self is SKScene {
    //var isPaused: Bool { get, set }
}
```

in which the property require that it can only be conformed to a certain class and or subclasses of that class?

UPDATE:
It seems that in Xcode beta 5 Apple changed how this one done considerably in Swift 3 and there is no documentation on it yet. It may just be that the feature is broken currently.

Comment: No because not all my SKScenes can do this. Only some can pause and I plan on expanding this greatly in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the requirements of a protocol based on the type which is conforming to it.

You can add restriction to protocol extensions, but not protocols.